# Multilevel b-spline crs issue in modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'm struggling with a processing modeler tool. I have a point shapefile (WGS84) which I want to interpolate with the SAGA spline tool. The model is reprojecting the wgs84-points to UTM32N (EPSG:25832). The next step is the spline tool. But I always get this error code:

> Error executing algorithm Multilevel b-spline interpolation 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details

When I use the points (reprojected manually to UTM32N) with this model (removing reproject layer tool, because the layer is projected to 32N) it works fine.

Is this a bug?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, the same error occurs when converting your method to a python and running it in the console or as a script.